# Enable/Disable or Add/Remove objects like chair and table from RoomPlan data on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, roomplan

I just needed to ask if there's a way we can discard certain objects when using Apple's RoomPlan API. Currently the object it return after scan is immutable.

```
 func captureView(didPresent processedResult: CapturedRoom, error: Error?) {}
```